# Establishing Duality in Tannakian Categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, tannakian-category

I sometimes need to prove a category is Tannakian. Part of the definition of a Tannakian category is that it is rigid.

However, I find the [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigid_category) of rigid categories somewhat difficult. I don't know how to show that these morphisms are identities.

Is there a way of looking at this that makes it more clear when these identities hold?

In my cases it is obvious that there exists a functor $D$ and isomorphisms:

$$Hom(X,Y) = Hom(D(Y),D(X))$$

$$Hom(X,Y)=Hom(1, Y \otimes D(X) ) $$

$$ X = D(D(X)) $$

$$ D(X \otimes Y) = D(X) \otimes D(Y)$$

So in particular I get maps $1 \to X \otimes D(X)$ and $X \otimes D(X) \to 1$. Is there a simple way of expressing duality in terms of a property of this functor?

Comment: I think you  only need to check $Hom(X\otimes Y, Z) = Hom(X, Z\otimes D(Y))$. Deligne's interpretation of rigidity in "Catégories tannakiennes, The Grothendieck Festschrift" (paragraph 2.2) is very illuminating.

Comment: @Mostafa Indeed it is.

Comment: If you have a fiber functor over the base field, then the category is already the category of representations of an affine monoid scheme. To show that it is a group scheme, it suffices to check, for example, that every object of rank one has an inverse object (i.e., the tensor product of the two objects is an identity object).

Comment: @anon Thanks - I actually knew that but the argument to check it is very inelegant in my case. I should have specified.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Mostafa points in the comments, it suffices to have a canonical isomorphism
$$ \hom(X\otimes Y,Z) \overset?= \hom(X,Z\otimes D(Y)). $$

But if I am not mistaken, you have
$$ \begin{aligned} \hom(X\otimes Y,Z) & = \hom(1,D(X\otimes Y)\otimes Z) \\ & = \hom(1,D(X)\otimes D(Y)\otimes Z) \\ & = \hom(X, D(Y) \otimes Z)\end{aligned}$$
using what you know (and symmetric monoidality, which I assume you have, as otherwise I would have expected $D(X\otimes Y) = D(Y) \otimes D(X)$).

Note that I only used your second and fourth properties.  I'm pretty sure that the second property alone is not good enough: you need some way to deal with tensor products in the first slot of $\hom$.

Comment: Yes, I'm symmetric monoidal. This looks great!